# Putting placeholders in a key/value List based on a Set of keys in Java

Tags: java, collections

I have a Set of keys and a List of key/value pairs. The values are of the form Long,BigInteger.

```
// key/values pairs: Long,BigInteger
List<Object[]> values;
// id list that corresponds to the keys for the list above
Set<Long> ids;
```

If any member of the key Set does not exist as a key in the key/value list, I want to add it to the list with a value of 0.

What's a good way to do this in Java?

Comment: Are there some strange requirements here, or can you use a `Map`?

Comment: Why are you using a List rather than a Map for key-value pairs?

Comment: mmyers/MAK: Order is important?

Comment: @Tom Hawtin: `LinkedHashMap` then?

Comment: You can't manipulate the order of `LinkedHashMap` without playing about, IIRC.

Comment: Well, we really don't know the requirements so speculation is the best we can do. :)

Comment: I'd suggest using `List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Long,BigInteger>>` instead of `List<Object[]>` for type safety reasons.

Comment: @MAK, btad: I'm using List<Object[]> because that's the type that Hibernate is returning from the database.
@Tom Hawtin: order is not important for the placeholders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The various commenters suggesting maps make a good point.  How about instead of

```
List<Object[]> values
```

you use

```
Map<Long, BigInteger> values
```

In that case:

```
for(Long id : ids) {
    if(!values.containsKey(id)) {
        values.put(id, BigInteger.ZERO);
    }
}
```

In fact, even if the code as must be kept as written I'd consider using a map for manipulation by pre-processing the list into a map, then dumping it back into the list of object arrays.

Answer (score 3):

> *What's a good way to do this in Java?*

Replace the `Set<Long>` and `List<Object[]>` by a `Map<Long, BigInteger>`. If the ordering is not important, then use [`HashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). If you'd like to sort automagically on keys, then use [`TreeMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). If you'd like to maintain insertion order, then use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

E.g.

```
Map<Long, BigInteger> unorderedMap = new HashMap<Long, BigInteger>();
Map<Long, BigInteger> orderedByKeys = new TreeMap<Long, BigInteger>();
Map<Long, BigInteger> orderedByInsertion = new LinkedHashMap<Long, BigInteger>();
```

This way you can just use any of the [`Map`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) methods to handle key/value pairs. E.g.

```
Long key = 1L;
BigInteger value = map.get(key);
if (value == null) {
    value = new BigInteger(0);
    map.put(key, value);
}
```

You can even get all keys by [`Map#keySet()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29):

```
Set<Long> keys = map.keySet();
```

To learn more about maps, consult [Sun's own tutorial](http://v) about the subject.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use something like one of the [Google Collections Multimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) implementations.  Don't re-invent the wheel.  The Apache Commons has something similar I suspect, but I prefer the Google library.

Querying for a key that has no values returns an empty collection.

EDIT: options for sorting order, uniqueness, etc are all available, just pick the right implementation according to your requirements.